# Convert text to numbers while preserving ordering?

Tags: string, sorting, language-agnostic

I've got a strange requirements, which I can't seem to get my head around. I need to come up with a function that would take a text string and return a number corresponding to that string - in such a way that, when sorted, these numbers would go in the same order as the original strings.  For example, if I the function produces this mapping:

```
"abcd"  -> x
"abdef" -> y
"xyz"   -> z
```

then the numbers must be such that `x < y < z`.  The strings can be arbitrary length, but always non-empty and the string comparison should be case-insensitive (i.e. `"ABC"` and `"abc"` should result in the same numerical value).

My first though was to map each letter to a corresponding number 1 through 26 and then just get the resulting number, e.g. `a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, ..., z = 26`, then `"abc"` would become `1*26^2 + 2*26 + 3`, however then I realised that the text string can contain any text in any language (i.e. full unicode), so this isn't going to work.  At this point I'm stuck.  Any other ideas before I tell the client to sod off?

P.S. This strange requirement is due to a limitation in a proprietary system that can only do sorting by a numeric field.  If the sorting is required by any other field type, it must be converted to some numerical representation - and then sorted.  Don't ask.

Comment: Can you do the sort outside the app. ie do a normal alpha sort, then your mapping is just the index in the sorted list?

Comment: @TonyHopkinson That would be an option if the data wasn't coming from the app itself.

Comment: What kinds of numbers are permissible? Can you do arbitrary-precision real numbers or fractions?

Comment: @templatetypedef I suppose so.  This was 5 years ago, I don't even remember what that project was :)

Comment: Hahaha, thanks. I just stumbled on this question and thought it was really interesting. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can make this work if you allow for arbitrary-precision real numbers, though that kinda feels like cheating. Unicode strings are sequences of characters drawn from 1,114,112 options. You can therefore think of them as decimal base-1,114,113 numbers: write 0., then write out your Unicode string, and you have a real number in base-1,114,113 (shift each character's numeric value up by one so that missing characters have the value 0). Comparing two of these numbers in base-1,114,113 compares the numbers lexicographically: if you scan the digits from left-to-right, the first digit that they disagree on tiebreaks between the two. This approach is completely infeasible unless you have an arbitrary-precision real number library.

If you just have IEEE-734 doubles, this approach won't work. One way to see this is that there are at most 2<sup>64</sup> possible doubles (or 2<sup>80</sup> of them if you allow for `long double`s) because there are only 64 (80) bits in a `double`, but there are infinitely many different strings. That eliminates the possibility simply because there are too many strings to go around.

Unfortunately, you can't make this work if you have arbitrary-precision integers. The natural ordering on strings has the fun property that you can find pairs of strings that have infinitely many strings lexicographically between them. For example, notice that

> a < ab < aab < aaab < aaaab < ... < b

Now imagine that you have a function that maps each string to an integer that obeys the rules you'd like. That would mean that

> f(a) < f(ab) < f(aab) < f(aaab) < f(aaaab) < ... < f(b)

But that's not possible in the integers - you can't have two integers f(a) and f(b) with infinitely many integers between them. (The number of integers between f(a) and f(b) is at most f(b) - f(a) - 1).

So it seems like the answer is "this is possible if you have arbitrary-precision real numbers, it's not possible with `double`s, and it's not possible with arbitrary-precision integers." I'd basically label that "not going to happen in practice" even though it's theoretically possible. :-)

Comment: This is true - but only if you insist on integers.  I didn't say "integers" in my question, only "numeric".  Then 0.1 > 0.01 > 0.001 > ... > 0

Comment: @AleksG Oh whoops, I totally misread that. Let me think this one over...